# 'Low Disk Space Warning' for individual drives

Tags: windows, gratis, monitoring, disk-analysis

When a disk is almost full, Windows will display a warning:

[image]

However this warning has some drastic limitations:

- you cannot change the limit on what constitutes "very low disk space"
- you cannot enable or disable it for individual drives, only globally for all drives.

I am looking for a tool that displays a similar warning, and does not have these limitations. I only need to display the warning, no further 'clean-up assistance' is required from this tool.

Specifically, I need to disable the warning for certain USB-drives, and for recovery partitions, while still keeping the warning enabled for the main Windows partition.

Requirements

- Windows 7
- Free for commercial use.
- Unobtrusive. Ideally totally invisible and silent unless disk space is low.
- Low resource usage. Should not have any noticeable impact on performance.
- ideally the look-and feel should closely resemble the native windows functionality.

Comment: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/188074 You can set appropriate values for individual drive letters.

Comment: @Davidenko I don't think this works, and a brief internet search seems to agree: http://superuser.com/questions/474242/how-can-i-disable-the-low-disk-space-warning-on-a-single-drive-in-windows-8#comment841318_617835 This is not the setting for the low disk space check that occurs in the background, but for the errror that is reported when you try to copy files to a partition with insufficient space.